# Return the average colour of Google images search results

Tags: python, google-api

Is there a way to get the average colour of a Google Images search in python?

For example this Google search for banana would return a shade of yellow

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=banana&tbm=isch

Answer (score 0):

I use this web service to get back the color of one image, but you can check image by image only, with Python library.

https://docs.imagga.com/?python#getting-started-request

## Example of code:

```
import requests

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''
image_url = 'http://docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg'

response = requests.get('https://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging?url=%s' % image_url,
                auth=(api_key, api_secret))

print response.json()
```

Comment: Thanks, this service looks really useful, but I don't think it helps me in this case, as I would still need a sample image to start with. Ultimately I'm for a way to return a (best guess) colour value from an arbitrary word or phrase. Using the google image search results was an example of how I might achieve this but I just don't know whether this can be done programatically